# Go mod use last version, not commit

Tags: go, go-modules

I want to use library according to last commit not to last release. So I got that version:

```
$ go get github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go@636ea43
```

Now in packages cache I have:

```
$ cd /Users/sgetman/go/pkg/mod/github.com/epsagon && ls

epsagon-go@v1.14.0                  epsagon-go@v1.14.1-0.20201105151128-636ea43d1943
```

But when I try `go build`, `go test`, `go mod tidy`:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go/epsagon/wrappers/gin
github.com/nexmoinc/neru-runtimelib/router imports
        github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go/epsagon/wrappers/gin: module github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go@latest found (v1.14.0), but does not contain package github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go/epsagon/wrappers/gin
```

At the same time my go.mod:

```
require (
    ...
    github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go v1.14.1-0.20201105151128-636ea43d1943
    ...
)
```

go.sum:

```
github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go v1.14.0 h1:Tq7qyoyDs2aUCc/UsQEHFt89aXVdUmjWXHwvS5kfSC4=
github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go v1.14.1-0.20201105151128-636ea43d1943 h1:kJGvRsqRfo1h8vEEGajWa+szA9965Epw83Fm3UmmwEc=
github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go v1.14.1-0.20201105151128-636ea43d1943/go.mod h1:Q73D3EhfzqmQa6m6Xi5n0Ugw9l6XSNGCzMcozsFMD1c=
```

Could you please help me to sort why *go mod* relys on the latest version, not version I provided?

Comment: At least, you should use this import path in your code `github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go/wrappers/gin`

Comment: i did, the same error

Answer (score 0):

The `go` command is checking the `latest` version because package `github.com/nexmoinc/neru-runtimelib/router` contains an `import` statement like `import "github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go/epsagon/wrappers/gin"`.

[`github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go v1.14.1-0.20201105151128-636ea43d1943`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/epsagon/epsagon-go@v1.14.1-0.20201105151128-636ea43d1943) does not contain such a package, so the `go` command is trying to figure out whether it can upgrade that module to a newer version in order to find the imported package.

If you run `go build -mod=readonly`, you will hopefully get a clearer error message. (Note that `-mod=readonly` will be the default as of Go 1.16: see https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16#modules.)

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me although I do not know if they are the recommended ones

1. Comment out all instances of that import path in all files
2. remove go.sum
3. did go mod tidy
4. did go mod vendor
5. did go get -u -d
6. uncommented the lines in all files again
7. did go mod tidy again